# Sql Server - Find two words in table column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want select data from table, If tableA contains these words > 'word1', 'word2':

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'word1+word2'
```

I want thing like this:

```
select * from tableA 
where tableA.title like '% word1 %' or tableA.title like '% word2 %'
or tableA.keyWord like '% word1 %' or tableA.keyWord like '% word2 %'
```

Notice: my conditionS are joined with 'OR' not 'And'.
Initial must splite @find like this:

```
@word1 = 'word1'
@word2 = 'word2'
```

Do you have got any idea?!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @findWord1 varchar(30) = 'word1' 
DECLARE @findWord2 varchar(30) = 'word2' 

select 
  * 
from 
  tableA 
where 
  tableA.title like '%' +  @findWord1 + '%' or tableA.title like '%' +  @findWord2 + '%'
  or 
  tableA.keyWord like '%' +  @findWord1 + '%' or tableA.keyWord like '%' +  @findWord2 + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like.....

```
declare @VarCodes varchar(max), @Xml XML;
set @VarCodes = 'word1,word2'

SET @Xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@VarCodes, ',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';

WITH X AS 
(
 select '%' + r.value('.','varchar(max)') + '%'as item
 from @Xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
)
select * from tableA A
INNER JOIN  X  ON A.title LIKE  x.item
UNION 
select * from tableA A
INNER JOIN  X   ON A.keyWord LIKE  x.item
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but your answer is for 'AND' between word1 and word2. I want 'OR' between word1 and word2